# how to make axios call synchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experiencing an issue where get_user() is running after console.log(usersOutput, 'here'). How can I change it such that get_user() run first?

```
function get_user(user){
        axios.get(`/api/admin/users`,{params:{idnum:user}}).then((user)=>{
           console.log('got user')
           return user.data
        })
}

var UsersFormatter = function(c){
    let usersOutput = 'waiting for change'
    var usersOutput = get_user(c.cell.row.data.sessionUser)
    console.log(usersOutput,' here')
    return usersOutput
}
```

Comment: It's worth learning about Promises and async/await functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *don't* make it synchronous, that will block the thread, which you never want to do. Just return the promise from the function and pass the promise around instead of the data:

```
function get_user(user){
    // return this promise
    return axios.get(`/api/admin/users`,{params:{idnum:user}}).then((user)=>{
        console.log('got user')
        return user.data
    })
}

var UsersFormatter = function(c){
    // return this promise too, so callers of UserFormatter can get the data 
    return get_user(c.cell.row.data.sessionUser)
    .then((data) => /* format data and return */)
}
```

Comment: What about web worker? I feel fine blocking web worker thread.

Comment: It seems *very* unlikely the OP is using web workers and asking this question in this form. But if you recommend using Axios synchronously in a web worker, please post an answer. I'd be curious to learn about that.

Comment: I have ended up using async/await in web worker. I think that's good approach as you don't need to learn different approach for main thread and web worker threads.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the axios promise and use async/await. So something like this:

```
function get_user(user){
        return axios.get(`/api/admin/users`,{params:{idnum:user}})
}

var UsersFormatter = async function(
    let usersOutput = await get_user(c.cell.row.data.sessionUser)
    console.log(usersOutput,' here')
    return usersOutput
}
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=await

Comment: I actually get the following error from your answer:
SyntaxError: redeclaration of let usersOutput

Comment: that is because you're declaring usersOutput twice. I just edited my code above.

Comment: UsersFormatter is also async. Then what is the difference between axios and your function?

Comment: Nothing, get_user is just a wrapper. I was just following his example.

Comment: UsersFormatter / usersOutput is a Promise not a value retrieved from the promise!

Comment: The code in this sample isn't even well formed. "var UsersFormatter = async function (" has no closing parenthesis